# Result is not same after merging html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

To make a bar chart according to this code -  http://codepen.io/CreativePunch/pen/AekEC  I merge html,css and js codes in a single html file. But my result is not same. Here is my code -  https://codepen.io/alimur/pen/MpdZYm . I think problem creates for js function, here is js portion-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
$("#bars li .bar").each( function( key, bar ) {
var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');

$(this).animate({
  'height' : percentage + '%'
}, 1000);
});
});
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: "Where is the problem?" is not an appropriate question. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: "I think problem creates for js function" isn't really a description of a problem.  Can you describe what's actually wrong here?

Comment: most likely you js is running before jquery is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've checked your Codepen. You are using jQuery, but you didn't require it. In codepen, click on the settings icon next to 'JS'. Then under 'Add External JavaScript' add this URL: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'

You need to load jQuery before using it. In your HTML you could load it in like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

***Example:***
[image]